# Renaming Array with Variable

Tags: javascript

One of the problems with teaching yourself how to code is that you miss some things that might be fairly simple:

I have written a function which takes text files (e.g. "someData1.txt", "someData2.txt" etc.) turns their contents into an array ("myArray"), and extracts their title as a variable ("fileName").

I am at the stage where I have parsed the filenames and the arrays, but I would like to rename each array with the variable, so that the first array becomes "someData1", and so on. I already have a bunch of code which will do various things with each different array, so it would useful if I could name them the way I wish.

I thought I could use valueOf to do it, as in

```
fileName.valueOf() = myArray;
```

but that does not work. So how do I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: huh? I have no clue what the final outcome is supposed to be... And that is not how you use valueOf

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way would be to use an object and then use array notation to assign keys to it. Let me show you:

```
var myObj = {};

myObj.someProperty = 1;
```

is the same as

```
myObj['someProperty'] = 1; // note the quotes
```

So, that makes possible to use variable names as keys. In your example:

```
var fileName = 'someData1';
var myObj = {};

myObj[fileName] = myArray; // myArray being file contents from your example
```

and now when you want to access the contents, you can simply do:

```
myObj.someData1
```

or:

```
myObj['someData1']
```

Just make sure you have no duplicate file names and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is defining a variable name dynamically.

It is not possible in Javascript though, but you can be tricky.
You have then two options :

1. Use the **global scope object** to store your variables (not a good practice) :

```js
global[variableName] = array;
```

And then you will be able to access it in the scope :

```js
global['toto'] = 42;
console.log(toto);

=> 42
```

This is NOT a good practice but is the only way to define a variable in the scope dynamically.

2. Use an object to store it :

```js
var myArrays = [];
myArrays[variableName] = array;
```

In each case you define in fact a property of an object.

You have to keep in mind that :

```js
myArrays['toto'] = 42;
```

is the same that :

```js
myArrays.toto = 42;
```

So to access your array, just do :

```js
myArrays.toto
```

Comment: I am unfamiliar of any global object called `global` ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects)).  If you assign a value to a variable that does not have a functionally scoped `var` then it will be hoisted to the global scope.

Comment: Yes I know it is not a good practice at all to use the `global` object, but it is the only solution to have a variable literally defined in scope, not as a property of an object.

Comment: Thanks! This did occur to me, but I thought there might be some more direct way of doing it. The list of files is not too long, so this will work.

Comment: @JasonSperske `global` refers to the global scope in Node.js, very much like `window` in web browsers. PS. If I need to set global vars I wrap my code in `(function(global){ ... }(this))` so I don't have to care how to reference the global scope in given environment.

Comment: Thanks pawel for the precision.

Comment: @pawel, Thanks, I didn't consider node.js, but after considering what the OP is trying to do, that makes a lot of sense :)